# template email html with a foreach in typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm developing an app and the user will have the chance to share the products via email.
Each product has a title, an image, a description, the ingredients and a list of energy values.

I've done it like this and I'm able to send an email with everything but the list of energy values

```
sendEmail() {
let email = {
  to: "",
  cc: "",
  bcc: [],
  attachments: ["base64:icon.png//" + this.base64String],
  subject: this.product.name,
  body:
    "<html><head></head><body><div style='color:#004119;'><b>Email Title</b><br/><h2>" +
    this.product.name +
    "</h2><img src='data:image/png;base64," +
    this.base64String +
    "'><br/><h5>" +
    this.product.description +
    "</h5><br><h3>Ingredients:</h3>" +
    this.product.ingredients +
    "</div></body></html>",
  isHtml: true
};
this.emailComposer.open(email);
```

}

The list of energy values is an object like this:

```
  "imageUrl":"/test/api/image/25",
  "value_Energy":"140kcal",
  "value_Fats":"14g",
  "value_FatsV2":"2.1g",
  "value_Protein":"1.3g",
  "value_Carbohydrates":"1.1g",
  "value_Salt":"3.5g"
```

How can I add the list of energy values?

[image]

Comment: console.log(this.product) and show

Comment: Is the list of energy values an array or what? We need to know the schema of your product to be able to help you out. As @AdritaSharma said, log `this.product` and update the question.

Comment: I updated my answer with the object of the products

Comment: How do you want to show the energy values

Comment: @sebba23 Check the demo I shared and let me know if you want something like this

Comment: @AdritaSharma I've updated the question with an image. It would be great to do it in table like that..what do you think?

Comment: Ya, but for that you will need the name of the title of the left columns which you don't have in the object

Comment: yes I don't have it in the object, how can I do it?

Comment: Well I did it... check :)

Comment: you are awesome, thank you!

Comment: Thank you :) Enjoyed doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the body at first and then assign it to the email object.

Assuming your product schema is like this:

```
  product = {
    name:"Product Name",
    description: "This is description",
    ingredients:"a, b, c, d"
  }
```

Try like this:

```
this.body = "";
this.body += `<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
      <div style='color:#004119;'>
          <b>Email Title</b><br/>
          <h2>${this.product.name} </h2>
          <img src='data:image/png;base64, ${this.base64String}"'>
          <br/>
          <h5> ${this.product.description}</h5>
          <br>
          <h3>Ingredients:</h3>
              ${this.product.ingredients}
          <table border="1">`;
          Object.keys(this.energyValues).forEach(energyValue => {
            if(energyValue != "imageUrl")
            this.body += `<tr>
              <td>${energyValue.replace('value_','')} </td>
            <td>${this.energyValues[energyValue]} </td>
            </tr>`;
          })
          this.body += `</table>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>`;
```

**See [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n6se4u)**

Comment: How about if i want to add the styles of the table like in the image?

Comment: You can add whatever style you want

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: Like this: ` <table style='border:1px solid khaki;color:green'>`

Comment: styles will work in your email. to make it work in the demo sanitizing needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
sendEmail() {
let energyValueSection:string;
//Assuming that you have a class named EnergyValue
this.product.energyList.forEach((energyValue: EnergyValue) => {
        energyValueSection +=    
        "<p>" + energyValue.energy + "</p>" +
        "<p>" + energyValue.fats + "</p>" +
        "<p>" + energyValue.protein + "</p>" +
        "<p>" + energyValue.salt+ "</p>"
});

let email = {
  to: "",
  cc: "",
  bcc: [],
  attachments: ["base64:icon.png//" + this.base64String],
  subject: this.product.name,
  body:
    "<html><head></head><body><div style='color:#004119;'><b>Email Title</b><br/><h2>" +
    this.product.name +
    "</h2><img src='data:image/png;base64," +
    this.base64String +
    "'><br/><h5>" +
    this.product.description +
    "</h5><br><h3>Ingredients:</h3>" +
    this.product.ingredients +
    "</h5><br><h3>Energy values:</h3>" +
    energyValueSection +
    "</div></body></html>",
  isHtml: true
};
```